# UIView does not load properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have the code file for my UIView set the the custom class of the view in the storyboard. But, when I run the app and the view is loaded, nothing happens? I don't get any of my NSLogs, nothing is drawn to the screen? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Am I not inilizing something properly?

My code for the UIView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"Drawling area loaded");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGPoint dotOne = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotOne]];

    CGPoint dotTwo = CGPointMake(10, 10);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotTwo]];

    CGPoint dotThree = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    [squareLocations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:dotThree]];


    int numby = [squareLocations count];

    for (int i = 0; i < numby; i++)
    {
        NSValue *pointLocation = [squareLocations objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint tmpPoint = [pointLocation CGPointValue];

        CGRect tmpRect = CGRectMake(tmpPoint.x, tmpPoint.y, 10, 10);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, tmpPoint.x, tmpPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);

    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use the debugger to make sure that your `squareLocations` ivar is not *nil* in the `drawRect:` method. You can send any message to *nil* without any error and actually doing nothing in objective-c. Also the initialization of `squareLocations` ivar in `drawRect:` method can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try add this code:

```
- (void)setup{
    self.contentMode=UIViewContentModeRedraw;
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    [self setup];
}
```